# onActivityResult not working with onBackPressed?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, onactivityresult

I have two activities, `Activity1.java` and `Activity2.java`. `Activity1.java` starts `Activity2.java` and I need `Activity2.java` to return some data back to `Activity1.java` when the user presses the back button on the Action Bar. But for some reason, it is not working...

Activity1.java:

```
public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
        int requestCode = 100;

        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        Log.i("TEST", "RequestCode:" + requestCode);
        Log.i("TEST", "ResultCode:" + resultCode );
        switch (resultCode) {
            case RESULT_OK:
                Log.i("TEST", data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE"));
                break;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Activity2.java

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
        intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", "Hello from Activity 2!");
        Log.i("TEST", "Setting result...");
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

When I run the app, only "Setting result..." is logged to Logcat. It seems like the onActivityResult override isn't even called. I've tried to change up the request code, result code, and setting the result in the onCreate() method of Activity2, but nothing works.

Could anybody help? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try your code by overriding onOptionsItemSelected > case `android.R.id.home`

Comment: and in Activity 2 try just `Intent intent = new Intent()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the result when you press the `ActionBar` back/home button, but you added the code in the bottom back button.

So, transfer the code in `Activity2` to be handled when the `ActionBar` back button is pressed, so Override `onOptionsItemSelected`, and the home button has an id of `android.R.id.home`.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
        intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", "Hello from Activity 2!");
        Log.i("TEST", "Setting result...");
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Although everyone's comments were really helpful and eventually led to figuring out what the problem was, this one was something I hadn't realised at all and I was testing with the Action Bar's back button all this time! So I'm setting this as the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling the intent correctly:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
    int requestCode = 100;

    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}
```

should be:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 problems with your code.

**1.** From `Activity1`, you start itself not `Activity2`. Change your code from

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
```

**2.** In `onBackPressed()` of `Activity2`, no need to declare `Activity1` inside the intent, change your code from

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
```

**3.** `In Activity1`, you should check `requestCode` before process further to make sure the data return from correct activity, because you might start more than one activity.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    Log.i("TEST", "RequestCode:" + requestCode);
    Log.i("TEST", "ResultCode:" + resultCode);
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        switch (resultCode) {
            case RESULT_OK:
                Log.i("TEST", data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE"));
                break;
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```